# Sonar - Code Coverage Reported, but Unit Test Count Not Reported

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

Recently, I've been running into a perplexing issue regarding Sonar that I can't seem to figure out. I couldn't really find anything on this specific issue online, so I figured I'd reach out and see if anyone has experienced this as well.

I am using the following:

- Sonar 6.0
- TFS 2017 Update 1
- SonarQube VSTS Extension 2.1.1
- Build server with Visual Studio 2017

When I am performing Sonar analysis after a build and after tests complete, it is detecting both the resulting trx file and coverage file.

[image: trx file detected]

[image: coverage file detected]

But once the analysis is done, it only reports code coverage. It does not report the unit test count.

[image: coverage but no test count]

Originally, I was using the following arguments in the "Additional Settings" in the Sonar Begin Analysis step to specifically point it to the trx:

```
/d:sonar.exclusions=**Scripts**,**Content** /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\*.coverage" /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\*.trx"
```

But I just tried removing all those arguments as I was told by a sonar rep in the past that you want to specify parameters from the site instead of by command line. When I removed my parameters, nothing changed (which I guess is to be expected). It still was able to find the trx file and still did not report unit test count.

I would try adding the vstest report path in the UI, but the issue is the path and file name are dynamically generated. The path depends on what build server/vsts agent the build is sent to, and the trx file name is generated based on date-time, and as far as I could find, there is no way to force the trx file to have a specific name.

I also checked the trx file to make sure I could open it and it reported test data.

Essentially, as far as I can tell, it *should* be reporting the unit test count. It did in the past but seems to have been not working as of recently. I'm not sure if this maybe was fixed in a newer version of Sonar? Unfortunately, I can't upgrade because dashboards were removed in newer versions of Sonar, and the organization I work for uses them. Has anyone experienced this issue before, and if so, were you able to fix it? Let me know if you need any additional information!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=..\**\TestResults\**\*.trx` instead (Additional Settings).

On the other hand, there is [SonarQube 2.1.2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) aviable.

My result: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhSpb9taJWFht7YB9

Comment: Sadly, neither worked for me :( . It is still definitely picking up a TRX file though, so this is really strange...

Comment: What's the result if you to do it on your sonar server?

Comment: http://imgur.com/5JbquRk so it shows the more general metrics, but does not have the specific metrics based on unit test count. Let me know if you want to see anything else and I can grab it!

Comment: So, it doesn't generate the expect result if you collect information manually on the server directly? Are there any report have the expect result?

Comment: That's when I ran the MSBuild Sonar Runner manually on the server, along with building and running test manually via command line. Ever since we've upgraded to TFS 2017, every build I've looked at so far does not report unit test numbers anymore. I haven't checked every build since there are so many, but I'd be confident assuming that none of them are showing unit test count anymore. Also, I looked at logs on the Sonar side for the analysis background task, and noticed it didn't list a report path for the trx file. I'm gonna dig me and see if I can find more. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @KyleRobertson Try to install Generic Test Converage plugin, then try again with my way. (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage)